# sampler value of texture from DisparityFloat16 pixel format on iOS OpenGLES

Tags: ios, opengl-es, metal, truedepth-camera, avdepthdata

I want to use depthDataMap as a texture from iPhoneX true depth camera on my OpenGLES project. Have downloaded some Swift samples, it seems that depthMap can be created and sampled as a float texture on Metal. But on OpenGLES, the only way to create a depth texture from depth buffer is,

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, depthWidth, depthHeight, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(depthBuffer));
```

The sample value is different from the value exported as CIImage from DisparityFloat16 pixel type. The value is much lower, and not a linear scale compared to the CIImage.

This is sampled value in OpenGLES
[image]

This is via code: CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithCVImageBuffer:depthData.depthDataMap];

[image]

Does anyone have the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like you're specifying the pixel data type as GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, try changing it to GL_HALF_FLOAT (if using DisparityFloat16) or GL_FLOAT (if using DisparityFloat32).

Also, if you want to display the depth buffer as a texture, you should be converting the depth data to values that mean something in a grayscale image. If you normalize your depth buffer values to be integers between 0 and 255, your picture will look a whole lot better.

For more information, [Apple has examples of this exact thing](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/AVCamPhotoFilter/Listings/AVCamPhotoFilter_DepthToGrayscaleConverter_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017556-AVCamPhotoFilter_DepthToGrayscaleConverter_swift-DontLinkElementID_6). They use Metal, but the principal would work with OpenGL too. [Here's a really nice tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/314-image-depth-maps-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started) with some sample code that does this as well.